# Use same argument name in modifier and function

Tags: solidity, contract-development, evm, modifiers

If I have a function

```
function b(address _foo) verifySomeClause {
}
```

and a modifier that can take different addresses as an argument, so that `msg.sender` can be one of those,

```
modifier c(address _foo) {
}
```

and the function modifier is called like this

```
function b(address _foo) verifySomeClause(_foo) {
}
```

and like this,

```
function b(address _foo) verifySomeClause(msg.sender) {
}
```

is there any problem with having the same argument name for the modifier and function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no issues with such a declaration. To understand this, you might want to look into [variable scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) which is how Solidity would evaluate the code.

Take a look at the code below:

```
contract Demo {
    event print(address _foo);

    modifier c (address _foo) {
        emit print(_foo);
        _;
    }
    function b (address _foo) c (msg.sender) {
        emit print(_foo);
    }
}
```

When you call the `function b`, take a look at how it will be evaluated. The `modifier c` will 'extend' the `function b`, which is what it is supposed to do. But when this call is made, `msg.sender` already has a value, and you'll supply the value for the argument `_foo` when calling the `function b`.

I have added the `event print` to make it obvious that those are two different variables bound to different variables. If you run the contract and call `function b` with a value different from the `msg.sender`, you'd notice that both the values will be emitted in the events.